# show_for gem gives to_key error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

hi i am using show_for gem and it gives me error like:  undefined method `to_key' for # in app/views/messages/index.html.erb where line #46 raised:

my view look like these:

```
46:   <%= show_for @messages do |s|  %>
47:     <%= s.attribute :subject  %>
48:     <%= s.attribute :message %>
49:   <% end %>
```

my controller code look like:

```
@messages= Message.all
```

please help me what i am doing wrong. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know this gem but according to its documentation, show_for is not supposed to receive a collection as argument (@messages) but a single object. I might be wrong.

With this supposition, I would to :

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
  <%= show_for message do |s|  %>
    <%= s.attribute :subject  %>
    <%= s.attribute :message %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```